# Calling exec_() on a pyqt application outside of sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
# some code
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

OR

```
sys.exit(app.exec_()) # This is how it is given in the zetcode tutorial.
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that in the second version, the return value of `app.exec_()` is passed as an argument to `sys.exit()`, which will become the exit code of the application. As stated [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> **sys.exit([arg])**
>
> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status
>   (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer,
>   zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is
>   considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like.

If you don't care about the exit code of your application reflecting the exit status of the event loop, you don't need to do it. I would say that it's a good practice to do so, since you may inadvertently mask the fact that your program exited abnormally if you don't bubble up the return value.